# request blocked by CORS policy even after setting headers

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a cloud function that takes the request and performs processing on the request. It works as expected when it is from same API domain. But in case of cross API request, I am getting the below error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at ’URL' from origin ‘URL2’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.
```

Even I have changed the code as suggested by google cloud platform but its not working

```
if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    }
    return ("",200,headers)
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
}
return ("Successfully inserted",200,headers)
```

While sending OPTIONS request in python, headers is

```
{'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Function-Execution-Id': '6bkxaumbvg7x', 'X-Cloud-Trace-Context': '2fd8aec285f8af1d36c8c45ff1184a20;o=1', 'Date': 'Mon, 25 Mar 2019 09:41:08 GMT', 'Server': 'Google Frontend', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Alt-Svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"'}
```

Please advice

Comment: Can you send an OPTIONS request to the server manually (eg using Postman) to check if the headers are being returned correctly? The request you should emulate is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: added my headers when Option is used

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response to the POST request from the browser? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.

Comment: In postman or in python this code works with the response code 200. But while doing the same in Ajax the API is throwing this issue. I am just wondering whether this issue is with python code or with JavaScript that is used to send Json to api

Comment: So if the status code isn’t 200 in the browser, then what is it? I realize that status code is 200 in postman or your python test code; that wasn’t what asked — I asked what the status code is for the response you get in the browser. What is it?

Comment: I will add answer in the below...thank you so much for your response. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have just commented out the AJAX commands below that is used to send request to the python code

```
//xhr.withCredentials = true;
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "cecaf566-fd7a-4992-8b65-cc66c074f264");
```

and it worked. 
Sorry for not posting AJAX at the first place because I thought the issue is from the server end to respond to request.